# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' in python

Tags: python

I have the following function in python:

```
def find_str(s, m):
    starting_points = find_starting_points(s,m)
    solution = []
    for i in range(0, len(starting_points)):
        position = starting_points[i]
        solution.append([position])
        solution = build_solution(position, s, m, solution)
    return solution
    pass
```

When I run the file in ipython, I get the following error:

```
     55     for i in range(0, len(starting_points)):
     56         position = starting_points[i]
---> 57         solution.append([position])
     58         solution = build_solution(position, s, m, solution)
     59     return solution

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: What does `build_solution()` return? Why are you using `solution` as an input _and_ output parameter of that method? @BrenBarn almost certainly has the right guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `build_solution` function is, at some point, returning `None`.  Since you set `solution` to the return of this function, you are setting it to None.

I can't be more specific unless you show the code for `build_solution`.